# Why user agent is different in IE 11 and Fiddler for the same request

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, http-headers, compatibility

When visiting the intranet site from work network, in the IE developer tool the mode is a compatible mode in the console

```
http://comm.dev.com/ is running in Compatibility View because 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View' is checked
```

and Request agent's user agent is

```
 User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; Tablet PC 2.0)
```

At the same time, when the fiddler is open then the user agent is different for the same request and there is no compatibility mode message in the IE console.

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Can anyone explain why the user agent is changing when the fiddler is open. This is a intranet website.

This site has X-UA-Compatible is set to IE=edge in the web.config which is coming fine in the response header

```
  X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
```

The compatibility mode is only happening from the work network but when visiting the site from home network there is no compatibility mode message and the user agent is

```
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

By unchecking `Display intranet sites in Compatibility View` will fix the problem but is there a way to do via code? Compatibility mode needs to be turn off for all the staff users. Or is it something which can only be done via GPO.

I have tried many solutions like adding a meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Even set in the header via web.config

```
<add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
```

None of the solution is removing compatibility mode when browsing from work network but from home network, all the tags are working fine.

Any clue or suggestion would be helpful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can set the group policy to unchecked **Display intranet sites in Compatibility View** option in IE.

You can try to refer steps below.

(1) Type **gpedit.msc** in run window to open **Local Group Policy Editor**.

(2) Navigate to location below.

> Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Internet Explorer/Compatibility View

(3) Find an option **Turn on Internet Explorer Standards Mode for Local Intranet**

(4) Double click on it to configure it.

(5) Click on **Enabled** option.

(6) Click on **Apply** button and then click on **OK** button.

(7) **Restart** the **Internet Explorer** to take effect of changes.

[image]